# Push to remote ref that does not exist

Tags: git, github

I have a local branch called X, I want to push this to a git remote branch by a different name that does not exist yet.

so I have:

```
git checkout x
git push origin x:new_branch_x
```

and I get:

```
error: unable to delete 'new_branch_x': remote ref does not exist
```

what is the best thing to do? I want to create a brand new branch on the remote with this action.

Comment: as a guess: `git push -u origin new_branch_x`

Comment: huh, let me try that :)

Comment: I think the -u option will start tracking or whatever, not sure if I want to use the -u option perse

Comment: or just rename it locally (before pushing)? git checkout x && git branch -m new_branch_x

Comment: yeah that's probably the better idea

Comment: savage attempt: `git push origin origin:refs/heads/new_branch_x; git fetch origin` then `git push --force origin x:new_branch_x`

Comment: You should not get such an error from `git push origin x:newbranch`. (What version of Git do you have?)

Comment: I am on git 2.12.0

Comment: For what it's worth, I updated my MacBook to git 2.12.0 and ran `git push origin master:newbranch` on a simple case and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @torek weird, I will try to get it working and report back, it makes sense that it should work, because my answer has no more reason to work than your solution.

Comment: @torek maybe it could be that github is using an older version of Git or something?

Comment: wonder how we can find out what git version they are using

Comment: If it's not prefixed with `remote:`, it's coming from *your* Git. If it is prefixed with `remote:`, it's coming from *their* Git. So this would be your local Git.  Puzzling!

Answer (score 0):

Given the comments, and my testing, the following appears to be the best approach.

Simply, instead of pushing the current branch to a remote that does not exist, checkout a new branch and push that one to the non-existent remote branch like so:

```
git checkout x
git commit -am "whatever"
git checkout -b new_temp_branch
git push -u <remote-name> new_temp_branch
```

this works and does what I need